# I can't open my code in the p5js app, I created the code in p5js web editor

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I recently make a code on p5js web editor, and when I tried to copy the code and paste it in the app it shows an error

I tried tidy the code still doesn't work. Maybe the app is too old

I'm just going to paste the entire code because I don't know where the error is.

- **Draw function**

```
unction draw() {
  background(220);
  seconds = time / 100;
  time = time + popo;
  fill(112, 166, 255);
  text(start, po, pi);
  fill(178, 178, 178);
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  fill(255, 99, 99);
  triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  console.log(seconds);
  x1 = x1 + trianglespeed;
  x2 = x2 + trianglespeed;
  x3 = x3 + trianglespeed;
  input.attribute('placeholder', "Enter speed");
  input.position(0, 410);
  if (!(input.value() >= 0)) {
    input.value("");
  }
  if (playing == true) {
    if (x1 <= 70) {
      trianglespeed = 0;
      fill(112, 166, 255);
      text("You lost.", 200, 200);
      x1 = x1;
      x2 = x1 + 10;
      x3 = x1 + 20;
      lost = true;
      fill(255, 76, 76);
      text("Press R to restart", 85, 330);
    }
  }
  if (aa == true) {
    fill(112, 166, 255);
    text("You Won.", 200, 200);
    fill(255, 76, 76);
    text("Press R to restart", 85, 330);
  }

  if (ab == true) {
    fill(112, 166, 255);
    text("You Clicked to early.", 120, 200);
    fill(255, 76, 76);
    text("Press R to restart", 85, 330);
  }
```

- **the setup function**

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  r = random(900, 4000);
  x = 100 - 20;
  y = 200 - 20;
  x1 = r
  y1 = 150;
  x2 = x1 + 10;
  y2 = 180;
  x3 = x2 + 10;
  y3 = 150;
  textSize(30);
  noStroke();
  start = "Click screen to play";
  trianglespeed = 0;
  lost = false;
  playing = false;
  win = false;
  po = 60;
  pi = 100;
  input = createInput();
  aa = false;
  ab = false;
  pressed = false;
  time = 0;
  popo = 0;
}
```

When i started it/click run, it shows an error:

> ```
> : Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
> "%cDid you just try to use p5.js's str() function? If so, you may want to move it into your sketch's setup() function.\n\nFor more details, see: github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup"
> ```

Comment: there's more code but i cant paste it cuz its too much

Comment: Are you using Node in your app? If so what version?

Comment: Please narrow your problem down to a [mcve] that we can run to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to add a "f" in front of "unction" in the first line of our code.

Since all the variables in the setup function are local, they wouldn't register in the draw function, making the error.

To fix the error, put "let" in front of the variables, and declare your variables outside of any function.